Does one need to repeat Birchas Hamazon if he forgot Ya’aleh Veyavo after washing again for the Afikoman?
If one forgot to eat the Afikoman, and he remembered after he bentched, so he washed again and ate the Afikoman, and then bentched again, and he forgot Ya’aleh Veyavo in the second bentching, must he repeat Birchas Hamazon?

M”B 188:26

מפני שאינו חייב וכו' - דדוקא בשבת וביו"ט שמחויב לאכול דוקא פת וא"כ חיוב ברהמ"ז קבוע הוא בימים האלה לכן תקינו רבנן לעיכובא ג"כ להזכיר שם מעין המאורע וכמו בתפלה … וכתב המ"א דה"ה ביו"ט יותר מסעודה אחת ביום וסעודה אחת בלילה שמחויב לאכול אם אכל ושכח להזכיר מעין המאורע בבהמ"ז אינו צריך לחזור כמו בר"ח אם לא כשלא אכל הסעודה בלילה שמחויב לאכול ביום שתים כדלקמן בסימן תקצ"ט דאז אפילו בסעודה שניה חוזר [פמ"ג]

One who forgot Yaaleh V’yavo must repeat Birkas Hamazon only after a seudah in which he was obligated to eat bread. In this case, although one who forgot Afikoman must wash again, the obligation is not certain, as per Shulchan Aruch O”C 477:2:

אם שכח ולא אכל אפיקומן ולא נזכר… עד אחר שבירך בורא פרי הגפן לא יאכל האפיקומן ויסמוך על מצה שאכל בתוך הסעוד' שכולן שמורות הן משעת לישה. אבל במקום שנהגו לעשו' שימור למצת מצוה משע' קצירה אפילו לא זכר עד אחר ההלל יטול ידיו ויברך המוציא ויאכל האפיקומן:

If one already made a brachah on the wine before remembering the Afikoman, one need not wash again and instead relies on the Matzah he already ate.
Clearly, the obligation to re-wash is a safek, in which case we do not repeat Birkas Hamazon. (Since the biblical obligation of Birkas Hamazon was already fulfilled. However, in general if one is unsure whether he said Yaaleh V’yavo it is not considered a safek, as it is assumed that he did not.)
The question would, however, remain in the latter case of the S”A quoted, which rules that one has until now only eaten Matzah that is shemurah mishaas ketzirah must wash again.
Here, one is certainly obligated to eat bread. The question, then, would be: is this special status given to any seudah one is personally obligated to eat, or is it limited to the amount of seudos the day requires one to eat?
[The M”B quoted above seems to suggest the latter understanding (“…since the chiyuv of Birkas Hamazon is fixed in these days…”), while the Magen Avraham he quotes points to a more individual chiyuv. See Shaarei Teshuvah 291:1 and the Machzik Brachah that he references, who opines that a seudah must be both required and usual in order to warrant re-bentching.]
